# Am I supposed to submit my application only by email, or by post as well, or do I query? Job posting for reference/ language below

Tags: faculty-application, tenure-track, assistant-professor

The job application description states: "Interested candidates must submit, by email ..... Send this and two LORs to:

[Enter snail mail]
[Enter email address]

I want to both; email and send my application by post since the dossier is long, almost 50 plus pages. Do I query if that is acceptable or do I just send by email?

Comment: If you do both, make sure the snail mail says that there's email too. Separate point: are you sure that 50+ pages is appropriate? No recruitment committee I ever served on would expect or read that much material at the start of a search.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @EthanBolker: How many pages are appropriate is probably a very culture depend thing. In my experience (pure maths in Germany), 50 pages is not uncommon. One reason for this is that many people like to attach teaching evaluations, which might already be 20 or 30 pages. Of course, nobody will read all of those 50 pages - but different members of the committee are sometimes interested in different parts of the application (and they might read more of it during later stages of the process).

Comment: It's hard to gather from the context of only the snippets you've provided, but my guess is that the application is to be sent via email, whereas the LORs are sent by recommenders directly either by mail or email (at the recommenders' preference). If you read the instructions with that thought in mind, do they make sense?

Comment: A comment I once (probably about 10 years ago) heard from a computer scientist about a job applicant who sent his application by snail mail: "What world is he living in?" Of course the situation may be different in the humanities.

Comment: Someone mailed  me a letter from US in the middle of December. Today is Feb. 3, I have not received it yet.

Answer (score 2):

If they give you the option of emailing or uploading PDFs, you can pretty safely assume that's what they prefer.  If you send paper (especially 50+ pages!), someone's going to have to scan it so it can be shared with the entire search committee or posted on their internal website for the rest of the faculty in the department to weigh in on.  Save them the trouble.